# Relative path for getting file in Tomcats webapps directory from a deployed web application

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

I am deploying a GWT webapp on TOMCAT, it has been successfully deployed and the war file is in the webapps directory. Now the app needs to access the file "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\TestHarness\modxml.xml". When I mention the relative path i.e "..\TestHarness\modxml.xml" the app is not able to find the file..
What should be the path, so as my app can get that modxml.xml file.

Comment: what about `/TestHarness/modxml.xml`?

Comment: My web application needs to access the file modxml.xml located in folder TestHarness and TestHarness is located in the same folder containing the .war file.

Comment: ok, in this case calling `/TestHarness/modxml.xml` should resolve your problem.

Comment: @MayurJadhav Are you accessing the file from a servlet?

Comment: Yes I am accessing through servlet..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend accessing this file as a resource from the classpath as opposed to directly through the file system.  Add the file to a directory on the class path such as a package within a source folder.  Then use the following code to access the file:

```
File file = null;
try {
    file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("modxml.xml").toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Although I would not recommend this approach you can get the location of your application from an `HttpServletRequest` using `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`.  You can store this value in a string, then suffix the path to file and use it within the constructor for `File`.